# Get months names between two dates Ms-Access

Tags: date, ms-access

I have this query

```sql
SELECT TblSales.ProductCode, TblSales.ProductName, TblSales.QtySold, Right([Zdate],7) AS [Mn/Yr]
FROM TblSales
WHERE (((TblSales.zDate) Between [Forms]![FrmSales]![From] And [Forms]![FrmSales]![FinalTo]))
GROUP BY TblSales.ProductCode, TblSales.ProductName, TblSales.QtySold, Right([Zdate],7);
```

I need this result to be like these columns (ProductCode-ProductName-Sum Of QtySold in First month from the given date - Second month - Third month - and so on)

Example : If the two dates were #1-1-2018# To #31-3-2018# -These dates can be changed due to [Forms]![FrmSales]![From] And [Forms]![FrmSales]![FinalTo]-

***Columns:***
ProductCode -ProductName -Jan-2018 -Feb-2018- March-2018
***Rows:***
A1-Computer-2000-2500-3000

Previous Qty is the SumOfQtySold in every month between the two dates,Thanks in advance.

Edit #1 :
I couldn’t make a crosstab query and this message popup [Crosstab Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nuksf.png)

Comment: What you need is to [Make summary data easier to read by using a crosstab query](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/make-summary-data-easier-to-read-by-using-a-crosstab-query-8465b89c-2ff2-4cc8-ba60-2cd8484667e8?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-5002361).

Comment: @Gustav The crosstab query have only one column header and one value column , In my situation we may need 12 column with the names of months between the two dates and in rows it will be the SumofQtySold in the months mentioned in the column headers , I wish I could explain more

Comment: Read again. That is exactly was a crosstab does.

Comment: I Tried and got the message in Edit #1 , Another thing what about criteria  Between [Forms]![FrmSales]![From] And [Forms]![FrmSales]![FinalTo])) , The last Question what about the column contains the months names in between ?

Comment: Well, everything is covered in that article, so study it. When done, create a sample using the wizard. Filtering is done as for any other query; column names @DenimChicken provided.

Comment: ok thanks bro i will look it up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a crosstab query to transpose row data into columns. Something like this:

```
PARAMETERS StartDate DateTime, EndDate DateTime;
TRANSFORM NZ(Sum(tblSales.QtySold), 0) AS SumOfQtySold
SELECT tblSales.ProductCode, tblSales.ProductName
FROM tblSales
WHERE (((tblSales.zDate) Between [StartDate] And [EndDate]))
GROUP BY tblSales.ProductCode, tblSales.ProductName
PIVOT Format([tblSales].zDate,"mmm-yyyy");
```

Comment: The crosstab query have only one column header and one value column , In my situation we may need 12 column with the names of months between the two dates and in rows it will be the SumofQtySold in the months mentioned in the column headers , I wish I could explain more